# Move all SKSpriteNodes except one

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

How could I go about moving all nodes in a view in the same direction except one? An example of the type of game I am creating would be a pokemon kind of structure where the main character in the center of the screen remains stationary at the center and all background objects move.

If anyone has any idea as to how I could accomplish this in the most efficient manner, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach is to add all your **moving objects** to a `worldNode` and then change the position of the worldNode. Add the character to the SKScene separately.

```
let worldNode = SKNode()
self.addChild(worldNode) // Add to SKScene
worldNode.addChild(childNode) //Add all nodes

//let character = SKSpriteNode 
character.position = centerOfScreen
self.addChild(character) // Add to SKScene
```

To move all sprites, change the position of the `worldNode`

```
worldNode.position = newPosition
```

Answer (score 0):

In the update method, use enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock: and pass //* to enumerate all nodes, then inside the block check for the name, and if it's not the one you don't want to move, move.

```
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"//*" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {

    if (node.name != @"nameOfTheNodeYouDontWantToMove") {
        node.position = CGPointMake(node.position.x - 1, node.position.y);
    } 
}];
```

Comment: could you possibly convert this to swift as I do not know objective-C?